# Cancellation Law for External direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove or disprove the following assertion. Let $G, H,$ and $K$ be groups. If $G\times K \cong H \times K$, then $G\cong H$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because use shows no effort to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $G = \mathbb Z$, $H = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ and $K$ is direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb Z$?